# Get data in the last three months using talend (Big Data Hive)

Tags: hive, hiveql, talend

I have a query to get all data from big data hive as source using talend

this is the query i usually use:

```
SELECT 
  bd_bt_xyz.xllnis05_timestamp, 
  bd_bt_xyz.xllnis05_key, 
  .
  . (too many field)
  .
  bd_bt_xyz.xln_cr_in_un_bl_dt, 
  bd_bt_xyz.date_pr
FROM newmisplus2.bd_bt_llnis05
LIMIT 1000000
```

And from now **i need to modified the query to get only data in the last three months in talend** and i still can't figured out how to do it.

*NOTE : field **bd_bt_xyz.date_pr** is a date of data creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filter:

```
where bd_bt_xyz.date_pr >= add_months(current_date, -3)
```

Something like this in Talend:

```
"select 
 ...
where bd_bt_xyz.date_pr >= '" +TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd"),"yyyy-MM-dd",-3,"MM")+ "'"
```